# Multiple columns in, IN clause Apache Derby

Tags: java, prepared-statement, multiple-columns, derby, sql-in

I have the below SQL query:

```
SELECT
    ORDER_ID,
    ORDER_CODE
FROM
    ORDERS
WHERE
    (ORDER_ID,SEQUENCE) in ((?,?))
```

---

```java
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)
```

The above line of code produces a `PreparedStatement` object successfully in Oracle with the above query but in Apache Derby, it is throwing the following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "," at line 8, column 14.
```

Could someone please explain how to query multiple columns in IN clause in DERBY.

Reference post:
http://apache-database.10148.n7.nabble.com/Using-IN-clause-with-multiple-columns-td98558.html

Thank you!

Comment: please share the real query!

Comment: Updated the post with the real query.

Comment: now can you show us your code please?

Comment: Looks like Derby does not support that syntax.

Comment: Why not: `select order_id,order_code from orders where order_id = ? and sequence = ?`?

Answer (score 2):

Conclusion: Derby does not support the multiple IN clause for prepared statement. (?,?) -- this syntax would throw an error.

Moving to H2 database for tests is better since it is possible to do there and more powerful.